# Apache 2.4.2 with PHP 5.4.4 crashes as soon as phpinfo() script is opened

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-7, php5, server-crashes

As soon as i open a `phpinfo()` script called `version.php` apache stops working. Here is the [`error.log`](http://pastebin.com/Nr8fyWaT) file. My configuration (my local development machine):

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64 SP1 with latest updates
- [Apache 2.4.2 win32](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/binaries/httpd-2.4.2-win32.zip) from Apache Lounge
- [PHP 5.4.4 VC9 x86 TS](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.4.4-Win32-VC9-x86.zip) from PHP For Windows
- `php5apache2_4.dll` (PHP 5.4.4) taken from Apache Lounge [php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/modules-2.4/php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip)

`PATH` environment variable is `PATH=C:\WAMP\Apache\bin;C:\WAMP\PHP` and installation folders (unzipping) are:

- `C:/WAMP/Apache`
- `C:/WAMP/PHP`

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 x86/x64 installed and updated. So everything looks fine to me. PHP integration in `httpd.conf` is:

```
# Integrazione PHP
LoadModule php5_module "C:/WAMP/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
PhpIniDir "C:/WAMP/PHP"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't assume that PHP uses the PATH variable to resolve the path of the extensions. So try adding the whol path in the `extension_dir` variable like

```
extension_dir = C:/WAMP/PHP/ext
```

Comment: Actually i found that Apache is crashing as soon as i run a script. I changed the whole question. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen PHP crash Apache on phpinfo() before when:

1. I was using PHP as a FCGID process and it was not configured right.
2. I was using one of the opcode caches such as APC.

Try removing the loaded PHP modules/extensions one-by-one to see if one of them is causing this.